# Leer columna con tipo propio - Rust - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, rust

He creado un tipo propio para una columna en una base de datos de postgres con el siguiente código:

```
CREATE FUNCTION time_subtype_diff(x time, y time) RETURNS float8 AS
    'SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (x - y))' LANGUAGE sql STRICT IMMUTABLE;

CREATE TYPE timerange AS RANGE
    (
    subtype = time,
    subtype_diff =
    time_subtype_diff
);
```

El problema que tengo es al leer ese dato desde Rust, una vez realizada la conexión a la DB intento recoger los datos dentro de un for de la siguiente manera;

```
  for columna in rows {
        let date1:NaiveDate = columna.get("date");
        let island1: String=  columna.get("island");
        let municipality1: String = columna.get("municipality");
        let address1: String = columna.get("address");


       let prueba: String = columna.get("schedule");
```

El compilador devuelve el siguiente error;

> thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'error retrieving column schedule: error deserializing column 5: cannot convert between the Rust type `alloc::string::String` and the Postgres type `_timerange`',

Evidentemente el problema es que le estoy asignando un tipo String a ese valor y no lo es, pero no se cómo explicarle qué tipo de dato es la columna `schedule` es la que tiene el tipo propio.

Comment: Hola Chambur, puede que [esto](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/issues/858) te sea de ayuda. Saludos!